# More than one row with the given identifier was found when calling findAll(), but works if I iterate trough all entries with findById();

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

Well...  I have an auto-generated database by hibernate and when I try to call findAll() in controller I receive that

> More than one row with the given identifier was found: 1, for class: com.example.rentacar.domain.Masina

Anyway, I checked database I don t have duplicates keys. This is the controller:

```
@Controller
public class MasinaController {
    MasinaService masinaService;

    @Autowired
    public MasinaController (MasinaService masinaService){
        this.masinaService = masinaService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/masini")
    public String getMasini(Model model){
        var masini = masinaService.findMasini();
        model.addAttribute("masini", masini);

        return "masini";
    }
}
```

service:

```
 @Autowired
    public MasinaServiceImpl(MasinaRepo masinaRepo) {
        this.masinaRepo = masinaRepo;
    }
    public List<Masina> findMasini(){
       var masini =  masinaRepo.findAll();
       return masini;
    }
```

this is the domain:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Masina {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String model;
    private Integer capacitateCilindrica;
    private Integer putere;
    private Integer anProductie;
    private String culoare;
    private String numarInmatriculare;
    private Float pret;
    private Boolean esteInchiriata;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "masina")
    private ChirieActiva ChirieActiva;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "masina")
    private List<ChirieFinalizata> ChiriiFinalizate;

    @OneToOne
    private Firma Firma;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "Masini",
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Categorie> CategoriiMasina;

}
```

The rest of object that are linked are empty(no-entries).
I tried to see what identifier is corrupted so I iterate through all entries to see what id will return me an error. After full iteration none of the entries returned error..
**The funniest part is that if I add this code in controller (iterate through all entries from db using findById before calling findAll) it WORKS !!!!**
So.. my controller looks like this...

```
 @RequestMapping("/masini")
    public String getMasini(Model model){
        for(int i=1; i<9;i++){
            var masina = masinaService.findById(i);
        }
        var masini = masinaService.findMasini();
        model.addAttribute("masini", masini);

        return "masini";
    }
```

Did anyone know why that happens? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Most likely something wrong with one of your entity definitions/mappings - can’t help you without seeing all of those

Comment: Can you post your `Entity` definitions?

Comment: thanks for your attention.
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding (fetch = FetchType.LAZY) to @OneToOne relationships.

Comment: In that case this is not a real one-to-one association but a `@OneToMany`